# Is it possible to alter an audio stream using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just want to be able to change the pitch, bass, speed and possibly volume when playing music through my bot.

I have looked at using ffmeg and modifying the datastream so help on that would also be nice.

```
playDl.stream(musicQueue[0]).then((value) => {
    music = {
        "url": musicQueue[0],
        "resource": discordVoice.createAudioResource(value.stream, {inputType: value.type, inlineVolume: true}),
        "player": discordVoice.createAudioPlayer({behaviors: {noSubscriber: discordVoice.NoSubscriberBehavior.Play}}),
        "connection": discordVoice.joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
            guildId: message.channel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })
    }
    const current = music;
    music["player"].play(music["resource"]);
    music["connection"].subscribe(music["player"]);
    music["player"].on(discordVoice.AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
        if (!(current["connection"].state.status == "disconnected" || current["connection"].state.status == "destroyed")) {
            if (musicLoop == true) {
                musicQueue.push(music["url"]);
            }
            commands["resume"]["method"](message);
        }
    });
    musicQueue.shift();
    message.channel.send("Resumed playing music");
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Im still having this issue, anything?